# Some NFA & REGULAR LANGUAGE & Equivalences

Tags: grammar, context-free-grammar, automata, turing-machines, automata-theory

I read some note about Automaton Course. i see this note, that following all is the same. but i think the L(g) is not equal to NFA and regular expression. anyone could help me with defining the language of this figures (nfa, regular expression and grammar):

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They are in fact equivalent, but this is a strange way of converting one to the other.

`R` is the same as `(a|b)b*`. `M` recognizes `(a|b)(bb)*b?`. The right part recognizes `2*n+1` or `2*n` `b`'s, where `n>=0`, hence is equivalent to `R`.

Now on `G`

`A` recognizes `(bb)*b?`, which is equivalent to `b*` (see comment on `M`).

`B` recognizes `bB|bb*|e` which is equivalent to `bB|b*` which is equivalent to `b*`.

`S` recognizes `ab*b*|bb*b` which is equivalent to `ab*|bbb*`, which is equivalent to `(a|bb)b*`.

Comment: would u please add a bit more detail?

Comment: thanks from your help. i confused again :) would you please wrote language of each them? why you add a question mark at end of M recognizes (a|b)(bb)*b?? thanks.

Comment: Wait a sec, answering you question about `G`. `?` just means 0 or 1 repetitions.

Comment: thanks, i approve it, but would you please clarify each of language. thanks.

Comment: you means S and R is equivalent but NFA accept another things?

Comment: No, L(G) not equivalent to L(R), and L(G) not equivalent to L(M).

Comment: In the Grammar G, the end symbol is not e, it's epsilon.

Comment: @MioMio Ah you spotted my mistake. I've fixed it up. btw, I'm using e to represent epsilon here for convenience.

Comment: @MioMio See my updated answer. You're right that L(R)=L(M) and L(G)!=L(R).

Comment: my last question is (a|b)(bb)*b how generate 2n+1 or 2n b in the right part?